# What is valid JSON for Bitfinex API Order New?

Tags: java, json

I have been vexed for several days by the Bitfinex REST API, specifically the private Endpoint to [place a new order](https://docs.bitfinex.com/v1/reference).

I was able to send valid requests to other parts of the API, such as Account Info or Key Info, etc. But I kept getting HTTP 400 error when trying to place any kind of order.

I have now got almost the whole API working, except for a few options. So, a JsonObject created with these criteria works:

```
JsonObject value = factory.createObjectBuilder()
    .add("request", urlPath)
    .add("nonce", Long.toString(this.getNonce()))
    .add("symbol", this.instrument)
    .add("amount", new BigDecimal(0.1).toString())
    .add("price", new BigDecimal(0.14).toString())
    .add("exchange","bitfinex")
    .add("side", "sell")
    .add("type","exchange limit")
    .build();
```

However the following returns HTTP 400:

```
JsonObject value = factory.createObjectBuilder()
    .add("request", urlPath)
    .add("nonce", Long.toString(this.getNonce()))
    .add("symbol", this.instrument)
    .add("amount", new BigDecimal(0.1).toString())
    .add("price", new BigDecimal(0.14).toString())
    .add("exchange","bitfinex")
    .add("side", "sell")
    .add("type","exchange limit")
    .add("is_hidden","false") // .add("is_hidden",false) does not work either
    .build();
```

I can't get any of the following parameters to work, using this code:

```
.add("is_hidden","false")
.add("is_postonly","true")
.add("ocoorder","false")
.add("buy_price_oco","0")
.add("sell_price_oco","0")
```

The Bitfinex API documentation is frustratingly sparse. (Their own "try it" example just gives HTTP 403 error). I found a really [helpful video tutorial from some time back](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rky1EnDqmhI), which showed screenshots of a previous version of the documentation that actually gave examples of valid JSON. Reading those pixelated still images was the only way I could eventually get `/v1/order/new` to work for me.

Am I missing something really obvious?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to print the response message to check the error:

```
....
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
System.out.println(response.getStatusLine().toString());

BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(
  new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

String line = "";
while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
```